# implement a database with key value pairs that can be stored efficiently where the key and value pairs are only valid for a specific time

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, garbage-collection

I am preparing for an interview.

At [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-experience-for-sde-1-12/) I found the following report of an interview:

> Asked me a technical question for implementing a database with key value pairs that can be stored efficiently where the key and value pairs are only valid for a specific time. Modified the version of the question every time to make it more efficient. It includes implementation of hashing, dictionary, garbage collection, and heap.

I cannot figure out the part where we have to make sure the key value pair is valid for a specific time.

I am assuming the first bit where a database with key value pairs is to be implemented is a dictionary/hashtable but I can only make that much out. Looking for someone to help me out with the rest.

Comment: *"Modified the version of the question every time to make it more efficient."*: What is "the question"? You start speaking of a database with key value pairs, and then suddenly start talking about "the version of the question"? I don't understand what this is about.

Comment: Yes the question is worded a bit oddly, even I am having trouble understanding it. I dont know if it'll help but here's the link where I got the question from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-experience-for-sde-1-12/

Comment: I'm sorry but you should then ask the person who wrote that vague description for clarification. What you quote is not really a question, but a vague story about a question that probably was a lot more specific, but which we don't have access to. It is not even clear what "heap" means here: the data structure? the memory pool? ...

Answer (score 0):

"Database" means durability, and to implement that efficiently, you're going to use an append-only transaction log combined with asynchronously updated snapshots of the dictionary.  The in-memory dictionary is updated as updates are written to the log, and when the system is restarted, the dictionary is reconstituted from the latest available snapshot and any logged updates that it's missing.

Expiry is easily implemented in a system like that, and actually makes it simpler.   In addition to updating the in-memory dictionary as updates are logged, you also process the log on a delay equal to the expiry time, and delete any records corresponding to delayed updates, if they are still current.  You don't even need the snapshots in this scheme, since the dictionary can be reconstituted from only the recent portion of the log.

You don't often get to take use an expiry mechanism like this in real life, though, because they usually let you specify a different expiry time for each record.  It will usually boil down to a similar kind of process involving multiple "expiry buckets", though.

If you want a lot of detail, you should look online for design information about memcache and redis.